# If a function is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[-1,\infty)$ is it uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it correct to say that if $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[-1,\infty)$, then it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

I don't think this is true but cannot think of a counterexample. Below there is an example of where I want to use this.

Thanks for any help

> Prove that $f(x)=|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

**Proof.**
As $|x|^{\frac 12}$ is differentiable on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ with the derivatives bounded then it is uniformly continuous on these intervals.

It is also continuous on $[-1,1]$ and so it is uniformly continuous.

It is therefore continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. If a function is uniformly continuous on each of *finitely many* closed intervals, then it is also uniformly continuous on their union.

Go back to the definition of uniform continuity on each of the subintervals: For every $\varepsilon>0$ that gives us a $\delta>0$ such that the variation of $f$ on a length-$\delta$ interval is bounded by $\varepsilon/2$. For a given $\varepsilon$, the $\delta$s for the various subintervals will have a positive minimum (because there are finitely many of them), and this minimum works as a $\delta$ everywhere. (Near an interval boundary, allot $\varepsilon/2$ of variation to each of the intervals. Bound the $\delta$ globally such that there is never a need to cross more than one interval boundary in each direction).

Comment: Thanks very much for that, really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for the original question, $f(x)$ being uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$, is **not sufficient** for it to be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ because we do not know about the function's behaviour in $[-1,1]$. But if it is given that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ then  we can deduce that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed it is a necessary condition.

Comment: I don't agree. Your argument would be valid if the intervals were half-closed, but both are closed, so the union is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @stevenvh — I think the argument is right. The function needs to be continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Lierre - the question is about -1 as endpoints of both intervals, not -1 and 1.

Comment: @stevenvh — Oh yes... But isn't it a typo ? I think we should read $[1, \infty)$ and not $[-1,\infty)$, and $[-1,1]$ instead of $[-1,-1]$.

Comment: @Lierre - I don't think it's a typo. It would be silly to leave out ]-1,1[ and conclude that it's uniformly continuous over $\mathbb{R}$. -1 and -1 mentioned 3 times in the question, and that's also how Henning in the accepted answer interpreted it. I therefore rolled back your edit.

Comment: How can $f$ be not continuous on $[-1,1]$? It is continuous on $[-1,\infty)$ implies that $f(-1)$ is bounded. So $f(-1) = f(-1)$ is trivially true...

Comment: @stevenh: I think in the "proof" part of the OP the questioner intended to use the property twice....

Comment: Sorry about my typo. I edited it. I believe the original question was about $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Of course if the original question has no typo, then it's a matter of choosing two points $x, y$ such that $x\in(-\infty,-1]$ and $y\in[-1,\infty)$ and observing that $ |x - y| < |x-(-1)|+|(-1)-y| $ so that there exist $ \delta_{1}>0$ such that $ |f(x)-f(-1)|< \epsilon/2 $ and $|f(-1)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2 $ provided that $ |x-(-1)|<\delta_{1} $ and $ |(-1)-y|<\delta_{1} $ Once you choose the minimum of the 3 $ \delta $s (one that work for $[-1,\infty)$, one that work for the $(-\infty,-1]$ and $ \delta_{1} $ ) you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon>0$ we need to find $ \delta>0$ such that for all real $x,y $ if $|x-y|< \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$

If $x, y∈(−∞,−1]$ or $x, y∈[−1,∞)$ then we have corresponding $\delta$ s which work. For the remaining case it's a matter of choosing two points $x,y$ such that $x∈(−∞,−1]$ and $y∈[−1,∞)$ and observing that $|x−y| \leq |x−(−1)|+|(−1)−y|$ so that there exist $δ_1>0$ such that $|f(x)−f(−1)|<ϵ/2 $ and $|f(−1)−f(y)|<ϵ/2$ provided that $|x−(−1)|<δ_1$ and $|(−1)−y|<δ_1$

Once we choose the minimum of the $3 \ δ$s (one that work for $[−1,∞)$, one that work for the $(−∞,−1]$ and $δ_1$ ) then we have the required $\delta.$